# Jackson deserialization - Kotlin data classes - Defaults for missing fields per mapper

Tags: jackson, kotlin

Given this data class:

```
data class MyPojo(val notInJson: Int, val inJson: Int)
```

Assume I want to implement a function of the form:

```
fun deserialize(jsonString: String, valueForFieldNotInJson: Int): MyPojo
```

Where `jsonString` does not include a field named `notInJson`. Assume also, that I have no control over `MyPojo` class definition.

How could I use Jackson library to deserialize `MyPojo` from `jsonString` and augment the missing field (`notInJson`) from `valueForFieldNotInJson` parameter?

#### Notes:

- Basically, the question is about deserializing a Immutable class, where some fields come from Json and others are supplied at runtime.
- Using custom deserializers or [builders](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBuilderPattern) will not work because missing values are unknow at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by combining [MinInAnnotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) and [ValueInjection](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureValueInjection).

Complete solution as follows:

```
data class MyPojo(val notInJson: Int, val inJson: Int)

class MyPojoMixIn {
    @JacksonInject("notInJson") val notInJson: Int = 0
}

fun deserialize(jsonString: String, valueForFieldNotInJson: Int): MyPojo {
    val injectables = InjectableValues.Std().addValue("notInJson", valueForFieldNotInJson)
    val reader = jacksonObjectMapper()
            .addMixIn(MyPojo::class.java, MyPojoMixIn::class.java)
            .readerFor(MyPojo::class.java)
            .with(injectables)
    return reader.readValue(jsonString)
}
```